# C - Replace substring in string

Tags: c, string

As a part in my process to learn C I am developing a couple of functions for string manipulations. One of these has the function of replacing substrings within a string, and is raising some questions. I am working in C99; compiling on Mac OS Sierra and FreeBSD.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *repstr(char input[], char rep[], char new[]) {

    char *output = malloc(strlen(input)*5); // <- Question 2
    int replen = strlen(rep);
    int newlen = strlen(new);
    int a, b, c = 0;

    // printf("input: %ld\t%s\n", strlen(input), input); // <- Question 1

    while(input[a]) {
            if(input[(a+b)] == rep[b]) {
                    if(b == replen - 1) {
                            strcat(output, new);
                            a += replen;
                            c += newlen;
                            b=0;
                    }
                    else b++;
            } else {
                    output[c] = input[a];
                    a++;
                    c++;
            }
    }

    return output;
}


int main() {

    char buffer[] = "This is the test string test string test test string!";
    char rep[] = "test";
    char new[] = "tested";

    int len = strlen(buffer);

    char output[len+5];

    printf("input: %d\t%s\n", len, buffer); // <- Question 1
    strcpy(output, repstr(buffer, rep, new));
    printf("output: %ld\t%s\n", strlen(output), output);

    return 0;
}
```

Question 1: When this line is executed in main() it causes a segfault. However, when executed within the function everything seems to work fine. Why?

Question 2: I have realized that I need a pretty large piece of memory allocated for the output to look as expected. strlen(input)*5 is an arbitrary number which seems to work, but why do I get seemingly 'random' errors when lowering the number?

NB! As this is a part of my process to learn coding in C I am not primarily interested in (more efficient) pre-fab solutions for solving the problem (already have them), but to explain the two questions listed - so that I can solve the problem myself.

Also; this is my first post in the SO forums. Hello.

Comment: `strlen` return `size_t`, so use `%zu` for `printf` format and correct type for variables. `new` is a reserved name for [tag:c++], you should avoid to use it as variable name.

Comment: 1. `%ld` is the wrong format type. 2. if you count the occurreneces of the substring first, you can calculate how long the new string will be.

Comment: Moreover: you have to check `malloc` return `!= NULL` (it can fail) and init the allocated memory due to random values the memory contains. Your call to `strcat` is UB otherwise.

Comment: BTW your segmentation fault is mainly cause by: `int a, b, c = 0;` Should be `int a=0, b=0, c = 0;` With your code the value of `a` and `b` are not inited to zero.

Comment: `output` in `main` is not big enough to hold the result!

Comment: Thank you LPs! Zero initialization indeed seems to have been the main issue. It's running smoothly now.

Comment: Answer to question1 is that len + 5 is a lot smaller than len * 5. Answer to question2 is that to write a string replace in C you need to do two passes, one dummy pass to calcuate length, then a second to write output.

Comment: Well, hope you zeroed the `output` `malloc`ated, otherwise stil UB.

Comment: Two standard library functions you might need: `strstr()` and `memmove()` (apart fron the realloccation problem, and the overlapping matches problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: When this line is executed in main() it causes a segfault.
>   However, when executed within the function everything seems to work
>   fine. Why?

No, `printf("input: %d\t%s\n", len, buffer); // <- Question 1` is not the cause of your segfault.

```
printf("output: %ld\t%s\n", strlen(output), output);
```

This part is, `strlen` doesn't return `int` but it returns `size_t`. As noted in the comments, use `%zu` to print it out.

Also, `while(input[a])` will stop at the NULL terminator which means that your `output` will never hold a terminator and thus `printf` will keep on reading, you should add it at the end:

```
output[c] = '\0';
```

*Also*, as noted by @LPs in the comments, you should zero initialize the variables you work with :

```
 int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
```

> Question 2: I have realized that I need a pretty large piece of memory
>   allocated for the output to look as expected. strlen(input)*5 is an
>   arbitrary number which seems to work, but why do I get seemingly
>   'random' errors when lowering the number?

Probably because you haven't allocated enough memory. Because the string length depends on runtime factors there's no way to know the exact memory needed you should allocate the maximum amount required:

```
char *output = malloc(strlen(input) * strlen(new) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already feeling a bit smarter. However:
Q1: I have replaced %ld with %zu, and am now storing 'len' in a size_t variable. The problem persists that if I comment out the line in main() marked with Question 1, the program runs as it should. If I keep the line I still get the segfault.
Q2: In this example the input string is 53 characters long and the output string 61. I still get odd behavior if I allocate strlen(input)*2, for example.

Comment: @BNauclér Did you add the NULL terminator and zero initialized your int's?

Comment: Ah! Zero initialization seems to have been the main issue there. I was of the impression that my `int a, b, c = 0;` would initialize them all to 0. Now this is changed to int `a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;` and it runs like a charm.

Yes, also inserted the NULL terminator.

Thank you!